# Connecting Vue to Express - 404 Not Found

Tags: forms, express, routes, vue.js

I'm creating a simple app to practice connecting Vue to an Express server. I have a form that I'm attempting to send to the back end, but I can't seem to get my data to the back-end. 
The error I'm receiving is:

> POST http://localhost:8080/login 404 (Not Found)

My best guess is that the method in my Vue can't find a matching route on my server? If so, I'm confused as I have a route for login.

**In my Vue script:**

```
const axios = require('axios');

export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
          user: {
            email: '',
            password: ''
          }
        }
    },
    methods: {
      sub() {
        var user = {
          email: this.user.email,
          password: this.user.password
        }
        axios.post('/login', user)
          .then(res => console.log(res))
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
      }
    }
}
```

**On by back-end:**

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..')));

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Server HIT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
})

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  return res.sendFile('../index.html');
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Express server listening on port 3000');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default express do not allow cross origin request i.e `CORS`. You have to enable it by setting middleware. add below lines in you server file and must be before declaring any routes

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! From my Googling I knew it needed middleware, but I didn't realize that it went in it's own function. I'm hitting my server no problem now!

Comment: glad to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

Express is running on another port than your vue application. Vue is standard http which is 8080, but express runs on 3000 with this line:

```
app.listen(3000);
```

You are sending the request to /login, which from the point of view of your frontend is http://localhost:8080, but that's not where express is available.
Basically all you have to do is send the request to `http://localhost:3000/login`, simple as that.

Comment: That makes sense, though when I do that I'm getting another error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000/login. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https`

Comment: I added the http:// and set the middlewear as Ghanshyam Singh mentioned in her post and all is well. Thank you!